# @keyup.enter unexpected result

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a single form with two vue 2.0 components.
On both components I have a single input field, combined with a @keyup.enter:

(Component#1) @keyup.enter="addItem"

(Component#2) @keyup.enter="addVariantItem"

If the focus is on one of the inputs and I press enter, BOTH functions addItem and addVariantItem are called.

```html
<template>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="variant-sku" placeholder="SKU" v-model="variantItemSku" @keyup.enter="addVariantItem()">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function (){
            return {
                variantItemSku: ''
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addVariantItem: function () {
                axios
                    .post('/articles/' + this.article + '/variants', {
                        sku: this.variantItemSku
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

```html
<template>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cross-seller-sku" placeholder="SKU" v-model="crossSellerSku" @keyup.enter="addItem()">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function (){
            return {
                crossSellerSku: ''
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addItem: function () {
                axios
                    .post('/articles/' + this.article + '/cross-sellers', {
                        sku: this.crossSellerSku
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

i.e. I am in the "variant-sku" input and hit enter, addVariantItem() gets called, but also addItem in the other component ...
Other way around, focus on "cross-seller-sku" causes the same result.

Is there some way to limit the @keyup.enter to the current focussed input? Right now it only works if one of the two inputs is focussed, if there is no focus nothing happens.

Is there a bug, so that the keyup.enter is called on every input?

Comment: Yeah ! Use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @DavidJawHpan if I do that, then keyup.enter no longer works / function does not get called.

Comment: Use in your function !

Comment: @DavidJawHpan figured it out: you have to call preventDefault on keydown, but I used keyup. I changed keyup.enter to keydown.enter.prevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to change @keyup.enter="function" to @keydown.enter.prevent="function"
since the inputs default behaviour is working on @keydown not on @keyup, which you have to overwrite.